# Payment Gateway Available on Github.io

Tags: payment-gateway, github-pages

I want to accept payments on my github.io site. I am wondering what payment gateway APIs are compatible. I made a paypal business buy button that worked, but I don't receive back a confirmation to my site that it was accepted.

The special part about this question is github.io doesn't allow dynamic scripts.

Comment: All gateways that involves JavaScript only should be useful on GH Pages. So, as far as I know, you can use PayPal STD buttons, yes. But you can't use PayPal Express. You can redirect the user to a "thanks" page on your website after concluding a payment, but this is set on PayPal itself. And the payment process will be available to you from PayPal only.

Comment: @VirtuaCreative How do I redirect them after concluding a payment?

Comment: Yeah, it's on the button configuration, one of the tabs bring you this possibility. I just don't remember exactly which tab and I'm not by my PC to check this for you, but if you go tab by tab you'll find it! If you don't, let me know and I'll give a look into that tomorrow and get back to you. ;)

Comment: @VirtuaCreative No. Could you write up an answer?

Comment: Yes, no problem. I'll post it in about 30 min OK? ;)

Comment: If you could also include how to make it secure. If I just have some random link that when redirected to, tells me they paid, how could I stop someone who didn't pay from going to the redirection link?

Comment: I believe there's a url to insert when the payment has been cancelled, I'll give a look into that and get back to you. Well, PayPal STD is not the most secure of all, but as the user is redirected to their platform, the payment process has PayPal security. But give me a little time and I'll get back to you, ok? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There we go:

1. Go to paypal.com and log into your account
2. Open the tab `Merchant Tools`
3. On the right side, click on `Buy Now buttons`
4. Set your button up on the first tab `Step 1: Choose a button type and enter your payment details`
5. Go to the tab `Step 2: Track inventory, profit & loss (optional)`
6. Check the first field: `Save button at PayPal` which will guarantee you this:

   - Protect your buttons from fraudulent changes
   - Automatically add buttons to "My Saved Buttons" in your PayPal profile
   - Easily create similar buttons
   - Edit your buttons with PayPal's tools

which will make the payment process secure.

6. Go to the tab `Step 3: Customize advanced features (optional)`

   - Here you'll be able to add a custom "sucess" checkout page - check this option and add the url to your "thanks" page:
     `Take customers to this URL when they finish checkout`
   - Here you'll be able to add a custom "failed" checkout page - check this option and add the url to your "cancelled" page:
     `Take customers to this URL when they cancel their checkout`
7. Click on `Create Button`
8. Copy the given code and paste it to your html `<body>`
9. Add this to the page `<head>`:

`<script async src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Create a new html and paste all the code given by PayPal, you'll be able to see the button locally (running `bundle exec jekyll serve`) and test it with PayPal Sandbox. You can do everything via PayPal Sandbox to test it on GitHub (or anywhere else): create an account, choose currencies,  create buttons, and so on. To do that, create a sandbox account [here](https://developer.paypal.com) and log into it [here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com).

When everything get to work as it should, you can do the same via http://paypal.com and replace just the button code with your *real* button code.

Hope to have helped! Let me know if you need something else :)